# How to view XML file with Wireshark - 3GPP TS32.423

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd, wireshark, dtd

I am trying to use Wireshark to open a trace file with the 3GPP defined format according to 3GPP 32.423 Annex A.2.2.  (http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/32423.htm)  There is an xsd file provided with the standard (traceData.xsd) but I cannot figure out how to use it to open the xml file in Wireshark.

From what I've seen, Wireshark can open XML files if there is a DTD, but I am not sure how everything works together (XML, XSD, DTD).

I appreciate any help that can be provided for this.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I've seen, Wireshark can open XML files if there is a DTD

It can?  It certainly doesn't have built-in capabilities for reading arbitrary XML files (it's a network analyzer, not an XML tool); it has some capability for dissecting XML files sent over the network in some protocols, *if* you have a capture containing the network traffic, but, even with a DTD (Wireshark does *not* use XSD schema documents), Wireshark's dissection is relatively unsophisticated.

You would probably be better off using an XML viewer or XML editor tool that can read an XML document in combination with a DTD or XSD document or, if such tools exist, a tool designed to read those trace files (Wireshark is a tool intended to read raw packet data, not packet summaries of the sort that appear to be described by 3GPP 32.423 Annex A.2.2).  (I don't have any recommendations for such tools.  You might want to change the title and tags of your question, so that people who *do* have recommendations might notice your question and answer it.)